# not able to scroll data with recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

How do i implement scrolling functionality with recyclerview. find the code snippet below.

quiztab.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/quiz_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

quiztab_mcq.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mcq"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:id="@+id/submitButton"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

QuizTab.java

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class QuizTab extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "QuizTab";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View view;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    List<Integer> usr_opts;
    RadioGroup rg;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiztab, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        getQuizContent();
        setupRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        return view;
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                VersionModel.data));
    }

    public class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private String[] mValues;
        private Context mContext;

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public final LinearLayout mLinearlayout;
            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mLinearlayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mcq);
            }

        }

        public String getValueAt(int position) {
            return mValues[position];
        }
        public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
            mContext = context;
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quiztab_mcq, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
 holder.mLinearlayout.addView(rg);

            }

        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

With the above i am trying to inflate quiztab_mcq.xml into quiztab.xml, but the content on page is not scrollable. my submit button is not visible on smaller dimension phones. It works fine with 5.5 inch phone but not on smaller dimension.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReyclerView isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712672/reyclerview-isnt-working)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

To

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.length;
}
```

Update: As NileshRathod mentiond in comment below, your hight of root `LinearLayout` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` not `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in `quiztab_mcq.xml`.

Also, about repeating: you will have it as many times, as many items are in your mValues, because your RecyclerView is creating list with its length size.

Update: if you want to display once your content there are no need in recycler view. RecyclerView is container for list items, but if you have content which height is more then screen height, you can use simple ScrollView or NestedScrollView. Then your content wont be duplicated and will be scrollable to end of it.

Comment: good catch also add this in your answer that hight of root `LinearLayout` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`  not `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in `quiztab_mcq.xml`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works. But now the questions and submit button is repeating 3 times.

Comment: I just want this content to be displayed once but it should be properly visible in all the devices, now keeping mvalues.length to 1, it shows only once, but some devices submit button is not visible